# Exception if terminating function reached in variadic template unpacking

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, constexpr

So I'm playing around with templates & constexpr, specifically variadic templates and I made the following functions:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr T get_argument(size_t index)
{
  return T();
};

template <typename T, T arg, T... args>
constexpr T get_argument(size_t index)
{
  return index ? get_argument<T,args...>(index-1) : arg;
}
```

The terminating function here is currently a dummy placeholder. So this function works, but returns a 0 if out of range, what I'd like it to do is crash...but it would need 2 modalities of failure. get_argument could be called at compile time, in which I'd want index being out of range to cause a compiler error. Or it could be called at runtime, in which I would like it to throw a runtime error...

I also have the option of this:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr T get_argument(size_t index)
{
  return false ? T() : throw std::out_of_range("Index out of argument range");
}

template <typename T, T arg, T... args>
constexpr T get_argument(size_t index)
{
  return index ?
        (count_args<T,args...>() ?
           get_argument<T,args...>(index-1) :
           throw std::out_of_range("Index out of argument range")) :
        arg;
}
```

But 1) I don't like the syntax (always false conditional, plus checking twice in a vague attempt to get the output to mean something), and 2) The errors is messy:

```
test.hpp:32:69: error: expression '<throw-expression>' is not a constant-expression
            throw std::out_of_range("Index out of argument range")) :
```

Anyone have a better way?

Comment: Have you thought about returning a pointer (null when out-of-range) ?

Comment: @MatthieuM. what would it point to in the valid case? Args exist only as template arguments...

Comment: Ah right, unfortunately without an `std::option`... I guess you could wrap it yourself (create your own simple `option<T>` with a boolean and default `T`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following may help (only one check):

```
template <typename T, T ... Ts>
constexpr std::array<T, sizeof...(Ts)> getArray()
{
    return {{Ts...}};
}

template <typename T, T ... Ts>
constexpr T get_argument(size_t index)
{
  return index < sizeof...(Ts) ?
    const_cast<const std::array<T, sizeof...(Ts)>&&>(getArray<T, Ts...>())[index] :
    throw std::out_of_range("Index out of argument range");;
}
```

C++14 may help, possibility to have several statements, as:

- local variable (which remove the need of this `const_cast`)
- `assert` (in possible addition to `throw`).

Comment: Interesting solution...why is the const_cast needed at all?

Comment: The temporary array is not const and `operator[]` is constexpr only for const object.

Comment: Ah that makes sense (I +1, cuz yes). The next question: In the case where this is called at run time, my method could be recursively inlined (if the compiler supports that), which (could, possibly, if compiler magic) reduce to a constant value return...would this fix have to do the heap allocation for the std::array? (I may have to just examine the assembly to get this answer, but if you know off the top of your head that'd be cool)

Comment: (This also fixes the problem if T doesn't have a default constructor)

Comment: `array::operator[]` is not `constexpr` in C++11, [you need to roll your own](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/706ecd408e827e07). Surprisingly, the code actually comes out simpler.

Comment: @Casey I'm having no problem with Jarod42's answer with g++...is that behavior non-standard?

Comment: @Jarod42 To answer my own question about the run time, both methods compile to 2 (identical) assembly commands (on G++) at-least up to a length of 32 items. Weird...awesome but weird.

Comment: @MadScienceDreams I imagine that libstdc++ has already implemented the `constexpr` changes to `std::array` from c++1y - I believe that would fall under the heading of a conforming extension to standard behavior for C++11.

Comment: @Casey I see...well, I'm going to probably go for a best of both worlds approach of `template <typename T, T... Args> struct ArgArray{ static const T value[count_args<T,Args...>()];}; template <typename T, T... Args> const T ArgArray<T,Args...>::value[count_args<T,Args...>()] = {Args...};`

Comment: @MadScienceDreams That's a great idea - especially of you replace `count_args<T,Args...>()` with `sizeof...(Args)`. [It's much better than our flavors at runtime.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/20221e17c21ed8bd).

Comment: @Casey I think it depends on the compiler and compiler flags, g++ -O2 assembly is all 1 mov and 1 movsql for all 3 flavors